# Interrupting an Input Process With a Timer

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I made a timer using Java that displays a "Time is up" message after fifteen seconds. During that time the user will input a message to copy. But after that time ends I want the keyboard input to stop. Here is the code:

Main class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TypingTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean a;
        String message, enter;

        Watch watch = new Watch();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("After you press <enter>, you will have fifteen seconds to copy the message.");
        System.out.println("Once you are finished, do not press any other button until prompted to.");
        enter = input.nextLine();
        a = watch.timer(15,"Time's up! Press <enter> to see how you did."); // message appears after 15 seconds
        if (a == true)
            message = input.nextLine();    // While timer is running
        else
            message = null;    // After timer is done running
    }
}
```

Timer method in the Watch class

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

class Watch
{
    private boolean running;

    public Watch()
    {
        running = false;
    }

    public static boolean timer(long delay, final String message)
    {
        running = true;
        delay *= 1000;    // Convert from milliseconds to seconds
        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println(message);    // message output after 'delay' seconds
                timer.cancel();
                running = false;
            }
        }
        ,delay);    // delay in seconds
        return running;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Watch.timer() method should be non static and after calling the watch.timer(..) there should be a loop to check the watch.running flag to interrupt the reading of the input thread.
2. The reading of the input, should be in a thread and need to be in a non-blocking mode, which mean, you need to check a flag to see if it should continue reading input data and also use the InputStream.available() method to see if there data to read and only use the .read() method to read in all available data, don't use readLine() it will block.